# reference and const confusion in C++

Tags: c++, reference, constants, temporary

I knew that reference is just another name of a variable, they do not exist as a separate object in memory but what is happening here

```
double i = 24.7;
const int &ri = i;  //notice int here
std::cout << i << std::endl; //prints 24.7
i = 44.4;
std::cout << ri << std::endl; // prints 24
std::cout << i << std::endl; //prints 44.4
```

My question is `ri` is alias of what ? [value 24 in somewhere memory]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind reference to object with different type directly.

For `const int &ri = i;`, `i` needs to be converted to `int` at first, then a temporary `int` is created and then bound to `ri`, it has nothing to do with the original object `i`.

BTW: The [lifetime of the temporary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) is extended to match the lifetime of the reference here.

BTW2: Temporary can only be bound to lvalue-reference to `const` or rvalue-reference.

Comment: I think this is correct, so +1. But is there a source for this? A requirement in the standard?

Comment: wow - i would expect that to not compile. I hope it warns

Comment: @pm100 You would think so, but apparently no: [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8d5929cc8f5b347)

Comment: No warning on GNU.

Comment: Correct answer, will accept in 5mins.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Their types don't match, so `double` needs to be converted to `int` before the binding. The converted `int` is a temporary, which is bound to the reference. Similar rule applies for pointer; we also can't take the address of `double` and assign it to a pointer to `int` without conversion.

Comment: right but this is *very* fragile code. If I had loaded ri from a function returning a float which then later gets changed to one returning an int this code will compile cleanly but the semantics have significantly changed

Comment: aha - fatals if you take out the const. So not so bad